# Error in react fetch from search bar | React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When using a fetch of images, and particularly when pictures from last fetch are not ready yet, it returns a previous array of images, instead of a new one. For example first call was test1 which returns 11 results, but when I change it to test11, which should return 1 result, it will return the previous array because during my new request, the old one didn't finish. If u do it when the last request is done, it works perfectly. I need to return a sorted array of images from fetch in a search bar.

```
    const [images,setImages] = useState([])
    const fetch = async () =>{
        setImages( await FetchImages({songs, token,removeToken,setUserError}))
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch()
    },[])
```

```
async function FetchImages({songs, token,removeToken, setUserError})
{

    let response
    const images = []
    // console.log(songs)
    // console.log("i fetched")
    for(let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++)
        {
            response = await FetchImage({id: songs[i].id, token:token, removeToken: removeToken, setUserError: setUserError})
            images.push({key:i,Url:response})
        }
    return images.sort((a, b) => a.key > b.key ? 1 : (a.key < b.key ? -1 : 0)).map((object) => object.Url);
}
```

```
const FetchImage = async ({id, token, removeToken, setUserError}) => 
{
    try
    {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/artist/${id}/cover`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'blob',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        })
        if(!response.ok)
            throw new Error(response.status);

        const result = await response.blob();
        return(URL.createObjectURL(result));
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        if(error.message === "401")
        {
            LogMeOut({removeToken});
            setUserError("You have been logged out");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Unknown error " + error.message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried both with sync and async, with hooks and without, but this async method is the most close to the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is you're not awaiting asynchronous calls, so they keep running in the backgourn. Can you give this a try?

```
const [images,setImages] = useState([])
const fetch = useCallback(async () =>{
    const fetchedImages = await FetchImages({songs,token,removeToken,setUserError});
    setImages(fetchedImages);
}, []);

useEffect(()=>{
    fetch();
},[fetch]);
```

Comment: Now the fetch isn't called when search bar input is changed, even when I add songs param to useCallback "async (songs) =>{..."